# Merging thick boundaries with individual districts

Tags: qgis, features, proximity, nearest-neighbor

I have this shapefile of Akron's city council districts in 2010.
[image]

For some reason the boundary lines are very large. What would be the simplest way of combining the with the nearest district? If the feature was smaller, I would use nearest neighbor, but all of the borders are one large feature. I know it will difficult to split the lines evenly across districts, so I don't expect the split to be perfect, I just want the city to be split by districts without a large area missing.

Suggestions?

Edit:I've uploaded the shapefile files in a google drive folder [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nF5uh6DbZ6TokkuE4Q7u8p0yZtApuw1_?usp=sharing).

Comment: This looks like a symbology issue.  Change the symbology of the polygons?  https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html

Comment: Hard to tell just looking at the screenshot. Consider making a sample of data available for prospective answerers. I'd probably start by rasterizing and then thinning the border to get it to a single line.

Comment: I added a link to the files.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach. It's not simple, but it will probably give a pretty good final result, depending on the steps and settings you use.

Start by cleaning up the source data. Select all the features with DN=255/district=NULL and update the district field using the Field Calculator:

```
overlay_nearest('Akron',"district",district is not null)[0]
```

Next, rasterise the vector using v.to.rast, once with no filter (**Rasterized1**), and once with a filter of `district <> 0` (**Rasterized2**). In order to match the resolution of your vector input, you may need to set the cellsize to 0.3 (your vector looks like it's possibly in feet rather than metres?)

[image]

Then, use **Reclassify by table** on the original rasterisation (**Rasterized1**), with a table of 0/0/1 and the settings below.

[image]

Finally, use r.neighbours with **Rasterized2** as the Input raster layer and the **Reclassified raster** as the layer to select the cells to be processed. The operation needs to be set to "mode". The Neighbourhood size will need some playing with. Probably start with 7. Too big, and you'll get bleed from other districts, too small and you'll miss filling cells.

[image]

This will fill most of the missing cells. You may need to repeat some of the steps depending on how much of the original data is missing. The red cells below denote ones that weren't filled by the first round of processing.

[image]

Once you have filled the gaps, you can then convert the raster back to a vector layer.